# How should my program create an error if a negative integer entered? (python)

Tags: python

```
while True:
    try:
        name=str(input("Enter your name="))
        age=int(input("Enter your age="))

    except ValueError:
        print("error!! please enter the values again")
        continue
    else:
        break

current_year=int(input("What is the current year you are living in="))

n=100-age
x=n+current_year
print(name,"",x,"is the year you will turn 100")
```

So how do I create an error msg for my use if he/she enter a negative number for the age, such that it allows the user to re-input the age.

Comment: Use an `if` statement that does `raise ValueError()`

Comment: You don't need to use `str(input(...))` since `input()` always returns a string.

Comment: Why don't you have the current year prompt inside the loop?

Comment: Your loop will make them re-enter their name if they enter an invalid age. Is that intended?

Comment: Allmdar Arslan,choose the answer you find most suitable and close the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `while` loop which asks if the age is smaller than zero. If this condition is satisfied (the user entered a negative digit), the loop will go on (it will ask for a new input):

```
while True:
    try:
        name=input("Enter your name=")
        age=int(input("Enter your age="))
        while age < 0:
            age=int(input("Enter your age="))
        current_year=int(input("What is the current year you are living in="))

    except ValueError:
        print("error!! please enter the values again")
        continue
    else:
        break

n=100-age
x=n+current_year
print(name,"",x,"is the year you will turn 100")
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try something using a while loop.

```
while age < 0:
    age=int(input("Enter your age="))
    if age < 0:
        print('try again')
```

We keep on taking user's age until they enter something above 0.